# What is the name of the new ubuntu font?

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-font-family

I've upgraded from 10.04 to 10.10 and so much of my preferences are set as they where in 10.04. I haven't seen much difference in the fonts used by ubuntu, do they have a different name? Which is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called the [Ubuntu Font Family](http://font.ubuntu.com)

In the UI  for the font menu it shows up as just "Ubuntu"

[image]

Comment: Couldn't resist commenting:"Dejavu Sans Mono" is also great for use as the "Fixed width font".

Comment: The “Liberation Mono” font is also a great choice for the “Fixed width font” setting.

Comment: Of course, if you're using 11.10 or later then "Ubuntu Mono" (which is part of the Ubuntu Font Family) is the best choice of all, and set by default. ;)