# What is default system font name?

Tags: 14.04, fonts, ubuntu-font-family

Ubuntu 14.04: what is default system font name?

[image]

EDIT: This font is **not** Ubuntu. Ubuntu font look different:

[image]

See the difference?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Lol, your dupe is a dupe itself. ;)

Comment: @wjandrea how far can we chain it?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I'm really tempted to mark [What default fonts are used?](http://askubuntu.com/q/69827) as a dupe of [What is the name of the new ubuntu font?](http://askubuntu.com/q/5811)

Comment: @wjandrea fontception.

Answer (score -1):

The default system font name is also Ubuntu.

Comment: This is not Ubuntu.

Comment: @minto Ah, then you're not asking about the system default font. The font you're actually looking for is called "Sans". It's the default font for documents.